# Get color of pixel in a scaled ImageView / Get ScaleFactor

Tags: java, android, bitmap, scaling

I want to add a color picker in my app and added an ImageView to the layout:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_colorpicker"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/color_picker"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.06" />
```

The following code should return the colors of the pixel, when the user touches on it:

```
img_colorpicker.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int[] viewCoords = new int[2];
            img_colorpicker.getLocationOnScreen(viewCoords);
            int touchX = (int) event.getX();
            int touchY = (int) event.getY();

            System.out.println(touchX + "-" + touchY);
            int imageX = touchX - viewCoords[0]; 
            int imageY = touchY - viewCoords[1]; 

            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)img_colorpicker.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(touchX,touchY);
            int redValue = Color.red(pixel); // I want these Values
            int greenValue = Color.green(pixel); // I want these Values
            int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel); // I want these Values



            return false;
        }
    });
```

**I think the bitmap has the real image size (2002 x 1127) so the calculated touch values are not correct...
I need to find out the scale factor of the bitmap.**

img_colorpicker.getScaleX(); -> returns 1

Comment: you dont need "scale factor" only, because you would also need the translation , instead, what you need is `android.graphics.Matrix`, read `ImageView` docs on how to get it

Comment: Do you have a Matrix example? I never used Matrix things, I'm complete new in Android :s

Comment: see `Matrix#map*` methods